# After zooming the position of an element is changed and hidden by another element

Tags: html, css, css-position

The problem is that after zooming the `.clinical_form` element changes its position and is covered by `.clinical_btn_download` element. Is there a way to keep the same structure without re-positioning after every zoom-in or zoom-out?

Below is my css script.

```
select{

margin-bottom: 1%;
margin-top: -3%;
margin-left: 16%;

}

.section_line{

margin-top: 2%;
margin-bottom: 2%;
border-bottom: 1% solid #DADADA;
border-radius: 3%;
background-color: #99CCFF;
width: 100%;

}

.clinical_form {


float: right;
margin-top: -8%;
margin-right: 30%;
margin-bottom: 2%;  


}
.clinical_time_tabHeader{

margin-top: 0.5%;
text-decoration: underline;
margin-bottom: 1%;
font-weight: bold;    
}

.upload_clinical  *{

display:inline; 

}
.cl_tb_btn_validate{    

 margin-right:10%;

}
.clinical_btn_download {

margin-top: 1%;
margin-bottom: 1%;
width:66.5%;

}
.cl_tb_btn_newdataset {


margin-bottom: 2%;
margin-top: 2%;

}
```

My html block is this:

```
<div class = "tab" id="clinical_timebased_tab">     
<div class="clinical_time_tabHeader">Time based</div>

<button type="button" class="clinical_btn_download">Download form</button><br>

<div class="clinical_tb_set" id="clinical_tb_set_1">
    <div class="clinical_tb_set_header">Clinical Set 1</div>

    <div class="clinical_tb_treatment">
        <div class="clinical_tb_selectTreatm_header">Select Treatment</div>
        <select size="0" class="clinical_tb_selectTreatm">

        </select>
    </div>


    <div class="clinical_tb_parameter">
        <div class="clinical_tb_parameterSelect_header">Clinical parameter</div>
        <select size="0" class="clinical_tb_parameterSelect">

        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="clinical_tb_sample">
        <div class="clinical_tb_sample_header">Sample type</div>
        <select size="0" class ="clinical_tb_sampleSelect">

        </select>
    </div>

    <form class="clinical_form" enctype="form-data">

        <div class="upload_clinical_header">Upload clinical form</div> 
        <input type="file" class ="clinical_file" text="upload form..."           accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"/> <br>
        <button class="remove_file" disabled="true">Remove</button> 
        <input type="button" class="cl_tb_btn_upload" value="Upload" disabled="true"/>
        <input type="button" class="cl_tb_btn_validate" value="Validate" disabled="true"/>            

    </form>

</div>

<button type="button" id="cl_tb_btn_newdataset">Add set</button>

<div id="dialog_popup" title=""></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you position your form element using margin-top: -8% and margin-right: 30%. This moves the form out of the normal flow, and although it takes a space to the right because of float right, the actual content is moved left and up, hence clashing with the other content. One solution could be to make the form float to the left and the div to the left, that way they are both on the same line and for smaller screens they will automatically stack on top of each other, like so:

```
form.clinical_form {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 2%
}

div.clinical_tb_sample {
    float: left; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xt95y/

This screws up the alignment of the selects because the containing parents are of different sizes since the last one is no longer the fill width of the screen because of the float:left, so i made it constant, you can change it around and play with it

```
select {
    margin-left:80px;
}
```